# How to change SRID of geometry column?

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I have a table where one of the columns is a geometry column `the_geom` for polygons with an SRID. I added a new column in the same table with exactly the same geometry data as `the_geom`.

This new column has the name `the_geom4258` because I want to set its SRID to 4258. What is the procedure to change the geometry's SRID to another coordinate system? Is it enough to apply the following query:

```
UPDATE table SET the_geom4258=ST_SetSRID(the_geom4258,4258);
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You should use the [ST_Transform](http://postgis.refractions.net/docs/ST_Transform.html) function. Also use the function [AddGeometryColumn](http://postgis.refractions.net/docs/AddGeometryColumn.html) to create your new column, to ensure all the necessary constraints are also created:

```
SELECT AddGeometryColumn('table','the_geom4258',4258, 'POLYGON', 2);

UPDATE table SET the_geom4258 = ST_Transform(the_geom,4258);
```

[ST_SetSRID](http://postgis.refractions.net/docs/ST_SetSRID.html) just sets the projection identifier, but does not actually transform the geometries.

Comment: Your answere is exactly what I need. So thank you very much indeed. There is just one small thing, now i got error:
"ERROR: AddToPROJ4SRSCache: couldn't parse proj4 string: '+proj=tmerc +lat_0=0 +lon_0=16.5 +k=0.999900 +x_0=500000 +y_0=0 +ellps=GRS80 +datum=ETRS89 +units=m +no_defs': unknown elliptical parameter name"

Any clue what should I co correct now?

Comment: Make sure there is a record for srid 4258 in the spatial_ref_sys table of your database. If there is a record, check that the projection parameters match the ones in here:
http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/4258/postgis/